# Is there anyway to check that an npm package has been published from the correct branch?

Tags: npm, azure-devops

So, we have Project A that has a develop and release branch. We reference a package from another one of our projects, Project B, which also has develop and release branches. What I'd like to be able to do is check that if I'm building / deploying Project A from it's release branch through Azure Devops that it is referencing the package that was created from the release branch for Project B.

My initial thoughts were to look into npm dist tags: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag but if I understand this correctly this doesn't guarantee that the package has ACTUALLY been published from that branch i.e. I could be on my own branch and simply publish the package with a tag of 'release'. Is there a way to automatically add a dist tag if you publish from a specified branch?

My next issue, which may well need to be another question, is whether there is a way in Azure devops to check against this package to ensure it has been published from the correct branch and if not then fail the build. So, if dist tags were used is there a way to check against a package dist tag as a part of the build to ensure it had the right tag e.g. 'release'?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT - not yet. I'm hoping to get a chance this week, so will definitely let you know the results!

Comment: Hi @ sr28 Did you try out below answer over the week? Please let me know how did it go?

Comment: Hi @sr28 Havenot heard from you for a while. You might have tried out below answer, Could you share the updates?

Comment: Working on it right now. Just talking with our devops team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question. you can automatically publish and add dist-tag to your package with azure devops build pipeline, which means you need to create a build pipeline to publish your package. And you can add a powershell task to guarantee that the package is published from a certain branch.

To add a powershell task run an inline script before npm publish task.

```
$sourceBranch = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"

if($sourceBranch -ne "release")
{
    exit 1
}
```

Above script checks if the [sourceBranch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is release branch. If the source Branch is not from release branch it will fail the task.

To publish your npm task with tag information. You can add a npm task to run custom command as shown in below pic. You can dynamic defined your tag name using the variables.(eg. `publish --tag $(build.Build.SourceBranchName)`)

[image]

Make sure you enable CI build for this build pipeline. And the trigger is release branch
[image]

With above steps, your package will be automatically published with your self-defined tag.

**2:**

For your second question, to check against a package dist-tag in you build pipeline. You can also add a powershell task to check the tag information of your package and fail the task if the condition fails.

```
 set-location -Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"

 $tags = npm view packageName dist-tags

 if( $tags.Contains("release") -and ($tags -ne $null))
    {
        exit 1
    }
```

Above script get the tag information using command `npm view packageName dist-tags`. and check if the tag contains "release". And the task will fail if the condition falses.